# how use rapidminer model in H2O.ai

Tags: h2o, rapidminer

i have created a model in rapid miner. it is a classification model and save the model in pmml. i want to use this model in H2O.ai to predict further. is there any way i can import this pmml model to H2O.ai an used this for further prediction.
I appreciate your suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

H2O offers no support for importing/exporting(*) pmml models.

It is hard to offer a good suggestion without knowing your motivation for wanting to use both RapidMiner and H2O. I've not used RapidMiner in about 6 or 7 years, and I know H2O well, so my first choice would just be to re-build the model in H2O.

If you are doing a lot of pre-processing steps in RapidMiner, and that is why you want to use it, you could still do all that data munging there, then export the prepared data to csv, import that into H2O, then build the model.

*: Though I did just find this tool for converting H2O models to PMML: https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-h2o  But that is the opposite direction for what you want.

Comment: @Dareen Cook , thank you for your suggestions.We have some pre-processing phase. we have huge data, is CSV will be able to handle huge data.

Comment: csv is the best format for H2O. csv compresses well, and H2O can read the compressed format. (However rapid minder cannot seem to write .csv.gz or .csv.zip directly, so that will need to be an extra manual step, maybe.) H2O can also read from a Hadoop cluster, if that is where your data currently is.

Comment: I think this is a good suggestions, after doing all your pre-processing steps in rapidminer  then put the data in hadoop cluster , from there use H2O to pull the data from hadoop cluster and build the model.